# How can we login/unlock ethereum account using keystore file as "UTC--<created_at UTC ISO8601>-<address hex>"

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, password

**What I have**

1. successfully unlock account with password using web3 `api(personal.unlockAccount)`.

**What I Want**

1. If user did not remember their account password, in case of that I want to unlock account via keystore file in private blockchain, if he/she has a keystore file of their account.
2. If it is possible, How can I get directory path of keystore file of an account and their filename by passing their account number programmatically (web3 api or other).

Comment: The keystore is encrypted with a password. You can not unlock an account with just the keystore file.

Comment: In effect, the keystore file _is_ the account. When you unlock the account, you're unlocking the keystore file.